# Homeomorphism between lower limit topology and another topology

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Given a basis $B$  for a topology  $T$  on R with $B=\left\{[a,b): a,b\in R-\left\{0\right\} \cup \left\{(-x,x): x>0\right\}\right\}$. Show that $(R,T)$ is homemorphic to the lower limit topology $R_l$.

**My Progress:** Since the basis of $R_l$ consists of open sets of the form $[a,b)$, I am trying to show that there exists a function $f: R\rightarrow R_l$ such that for any basis open sets $[a,b)$,  $f^{-1} ([a,b))$ is open in $B$. I haven't been able to find such a function $f$ to work with, so can anyone give some hints on this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: For $n\in\Bbb N$ let $$I_n=\left[\frac1{2^{n+1}},\frac1{2^n}\right)\;.$$(Note: $0\in\Bbb N$.) Let $L=(\leftarrow,0)$ and $R=[1,\to)$. The sets $L,R$, and $I_n$ for $n\in\Bbb N$ are all clopen in $\Bbb R_\ell$. Now rearrange them, together with the point $0$, as shown here:

$$L\quad I_1\quad I_3\quad I_5\;\ldots\; 0\;\ldots\; I_4\quad I_2\quad I_0\quad R$$

**Added:** For $n\in\Bbb N$ let

$$J_n=\left[-\frac1{2^n},-\frac1{2^{n+1}}\right)\;.$$

For each $n\in\Bbb N$ there are order-isomorphisms $f_n:I_{2n+1}\to J_n$ and $g_n:I_{2n}\to I_n$. Define

$$h:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R:x\mapsto\begin{cases}
x,&\text{if }x\in R\cup\{0\}\\
g_n(x),&\text{if }x\in I_{2n}\\
f_n(x),&\text{if }x\in I_{2n+1}\\
x-1,&\text{if }x\in L\;.
\end{cases}$$

Show that if the domain has the lower-limit topology, and the range has the topology $T$, then $h$ is a homeomorphism.

$$\begin{array}{rcc}
L&I_1&I_3&I_5&\ldots&0&\ldots&I_4&I_2&I_0&R\\
&&&&&\;\;\;\downarrow h\\
(\leftarrow,-1)&J_0&J_1&J_2&\ldots&0&\ldots&I_2&I_1&I_0&R
\end{array}$$

**Added<sub>2</sub>:** Let $x\in\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$; then a basic open nbhd of $h(x)$ has the form $[h(x),y)$ for some $y>h(x)$. If $x\in R$, then $[x,y)$ is an open nbhd of $x$ that maps onto $[h(x),y)$. If $x\in I_{2n}$ for some $n\in\Bbb N$, choose $z\in I_{2n}$ such that $x<z$ and $h(z)=g_n(z)\le y$; this is always possible, and $h$ maps $[x,z)$ into $[h(x),y)$. If $x\in I_{2n+1}$ for some $n\in\Bbb N$, choose $z\in I_{2n+1}$ such that $x<z$ and $h(z)=f_n(z)\le y$; this is always possible, and $h$ maps $[x,z)$ into $[h(x),y)$. Finally, if $x\in L$, let $z=y+1$; then $h$ maps $[x,z)$ onto $[h(x),y)$.

Now let $(-x,x)$ be a basic open nbhd of $h(0)=0$. There is an $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $2^{-n}<x$; clearly $I_k\subseteq(0,x)$ for all $k\ge n$. Let $B=\{0\}\cup\bigcup_{k\ge n}I_{2k}$; then $B$ is an open nbhd of $0$ in the domain of $h$, and $h[B]=\{0\}\cup\bigcup_{k\ge n}I_k\subseteq(-x,x)$.

We’ve now shown that $h$ is continuous at every point of its domain and therefore is continuous.

Comment: M.Scott: I'm sorry Professor Scott, but I can't see how this implies homeomorphism, especially because your hint doesn't seem to use the fact that $B$ contains $\left\{(-x,x): x>0\right\}.$

Comment: @user177196: What do nbhds of $0$ look like in the rearranged line?

Comment: @user177196: I decided that more help was probably needed. The map $h$ is just a formal expression of the rearrangement that I suggested.

Comment: I think I got this proof for why $h$ is homeomorphism, but I'm not too sure: let $U$ be any open set in the range, then we want to show $h^{-1}(U) is open$. By the definition of $h$ above, $h^{-1}(U)$ is a subset of either $R\cup {0}$, $I_{2n}$.  $I_(2n+1)$, or $L$. In the first case, if it's a subset of $R$ or $0$, then there always exists a half-open interval that is open in the domain and containing $h^{-1}(U)$. The case that it's a subset of $I_{2n}$ or $I_{2n+1}$ is because $h^{-1}(g_n(x)),h^{-1}(f_n(x))$ belongs to one of half-open interval in $I_2n$ or $I_{2n+1}$.

Comment: The last case is a bit hard, but since $x$ is not infinite, $h^{-1}(x-1)$ is a subset of $(-\infty, 0)$, but obviously any such subset with lower bound not infinity can be contained in a lower-limit interval $[a,b)$ with suitable values of $a$ and $b$. Please let me know if my proof for all these cases is correct.

Comment: @user177196: In this case it might be a little easier to show that $h$ is continuous at each point (rather than trying to show global continuity all at once). This is especially likely to be the case at $0$. (It would also help if I’d not interchanged *domain* and *range* in the last sentence; fixed now.)

Comment: @user177196: You can’t say that $h^{-1}[U]$ is a subset of one of the pieces: it might contain many pieces, or a piece and part of another, or ... . I really would try to prove it by showing continuity at each point of the domain: show that for any $x$ in the domain and open nbhd $U$ of $h(x)$ there is an open nbhd $B$ of $x$ in the domain such that $h[B]\subseteq U$.

Comment: @user177196: $\{0\}$ is definitely not in $T$. To be honest, I can’t make sense of your argument: it appears to me that you have some confusion about what’s required to show that a function is continuous, but I can’t tell just where the confusion lies. Try something concrete. $[0,1/3)$ is an open nbhd of $0$ in the range of $h$; what is a $T$-open nbhd of $0$ in the domain that maps inside $[0,1/3)$?

Comment: I'm seriously stuck:(( Can you please help with the T-open nbhd of $0$? I tried 4 cases corresponding to each $x$, but in each case, couldn't find any such $T-open$ nbhd of $0$ that maps inside the given interval:P

Comment: can you please give me some last help by proving the proof for the continuity part, Prof. Scott? I really apologize for not being able to solve this problem much:P, but I tried and failed, even on your concrete example.

Comment: @user177196: Sorry: I was busy on something else. I also loused up my last couple of comments, because I was trying to do two things at once. My original last sentence was correct: the range has the $T$ topology. Let $(-x,x)$ be an open nbhd of $0$ in the range. Then there is an $n$ such that $I_k,J_k\subseteq(-x,x)$ for all $k\ge n$, and $\{0\}\cup\bigcup_{k\ge n}I_k$ is an open nbhd of $0$ in the domain that $h$ maps into $(-x,x)$.

Comment: can you please help complete proof for the continuity, since I still stuck on this proof despite using the procedure you mentioned above:P

Comment: @user177196: I just added the proof of continuity.