# No continuous map from usual topology $(\mathbb{R}, \tau_u)$ to the lower limit topology $(\mathbb{R}, \tau_l)$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, continuity

Given two basis for the set of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$, $B=\{(a,b): a,b\in R\}$ and $B'=\{(a,b]: a,b\in R\}$. Now the topology generated by the basis $B$ on $\mathbb{R}$ is called as usual topology $(\mathbb{R}, \tau_u)$ and by B' is called as lower limit topology $(\mathbb{R}, \tau_l)$.

It is well known result that  $\mathbb{R}$  with lower limit topology is finer than the the usual topology.

**My Question** Can we claim that there is no continuous map from $(\mathbb{R}, \tau_u)$ to $(\mathbb{R}, \tau_l)$ other than the trivial map.

I have seen many question regarding usual topology and lower limit topology on this platform, but  not getting my answer from these

- [Homeomorphism between lower limit topology and another topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1175655/homeomorphism-between-lower-limit-topology-and-another-topology)
- [Find a function that is continuous in usual topology, discontinuous in lower limit topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1814031/find-a-function-that-is-continuous-in-usual-topology-discontinuous-in-lower-lim)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no continuous map from the usual topology to the lower-limit topology, except constant maps.

If such a map $f$ were to attain distinct values $a$ and $b$, where $a<b$, then $f^{-1}[b,\infty)$ would be closed and also open in $\tau_u$, which is impossible because the only clopen subsets of $\tau_u$ are the whole set and the empty set.

Comment: @chirs saners thanks for the nice explanation. Here you are using the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is connected.